# How to Record WebCam Video in MPEG or AVI files using C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, video, video-capture, video-recording

I am developing a Desktop Application which requires me to connect to webcam(s) and record(save) the video in MPEG, AVI, MP4 and WMV formats and Burn into the CD/DVD. The application is in Win Forms. I am only Looking for free or open source solutions or controls.

I had done saving as AVI using Aforge.Net but its taking more size to save(like 60-100MB for 15sce 320x240 Video ). I am expecting 1MB for 10sec.
Here is the Code :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace Aforge_Web_Cam
{
public partial class VideoForm : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
    private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
    private Bitmap video;
    private AVIWriter AVIwriter = new AVIWriter();
    private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;

    public VideoForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void VideoForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
    }

    private void butStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }
    }

    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pbVideo.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
            AVIwriter.AddFrame(video);
        }
        else
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pbVideo.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
    }

    private void butRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
        if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
            int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
            AVIwriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h);
            butStop.Text = "Stop Record";
            //FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            //FinalVideo.Start();
        }
    }

    private void butStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            butStop.Text = "Stop";
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pbVideo.Image = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            this.AVIwriter.Close();
            pbVideo.Image = null;
        }
    }

    private void butCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pbVideo.Image.Save("IMG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
    }

    private void butCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void VideoForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalVideo == null)
        { return; }
        if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            this.AVIwriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot just "save as AVI", you have to encode the video to your desired format. (AVI is merely a container, btw, not a format.)

Comment: if you know to encode, pls send code for encode video.  thanks for comment

Comment: Come on, show a little effort!

Comment: i am trying from last 2 weeks i didn't get the proper code for recording video sure i am going try more but i needed little help.

Comment: i made it by VideoFileWriter [link](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/)

Comment: Observation: Never base your application's functionality with the application's interface ->  if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record"). Set a flag to that

Answer (score 7):

AVIWriter doesn't provide videocompression, use FileWriter from AForge.Video.FFMPEG. There you can choose everything: Size, Framerate, Codec and Bitrate and if your video was 600MB in 20 sec it now will be 6 MB in 20 sec.

Here you go:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;

        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
        private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
        private Bitmap video;
        //private AVIWriter AVIwriter = new AVIWriter();
        private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }
        void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                //AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
                //AVIwriter.AddFrame(video);
            }
            else
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
            if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
                int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
                FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h,25,VideoCodec.Default,5000000);
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);

                //AVIwriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h);
                butStop.Text = "Stop Record";
                //FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                //FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }

        private void butStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                butStop.Text = "Stop";
                if (FinalVideo == null)
                { return; }
                if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
                {
                    //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                    FileWriter.Close();
                    //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save("IMG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: can't find VideoFileWriter, which nuget package should i use, i have already added `AForge.Video` and `AForge.Video.DirectShow`

Comment: use this cmd to install,       Install-Package Accord.Video.FFMPEG -Version 3.8.0