# How to Record Video Using Webcam and C#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, aforge

I'm trying to build my video recording app using my webcam and save the output in my hard disk or SQL database, but there is no series tutorial to explain what I mean, most of them explain how to capture image not recording video.

When I'm searching I found this question [How to Record WebCam Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468863/how-to-record-webcam-video-in-mpeg-or-avi-files-using-c-sharp-desktop-applicatio)
and I built the question program and it is working with his problem but when I fixed it from the question solution this exception generated

> **Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.**

I'm trying to fix it with many solutions which I found but without any change.
I don't know which solution is working fine or which one is not?!

Comment: Did you add a reference to the `AForge.Video.FFMPEG dll` in your project?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my project.